# ImportError: cannot import name 'mutual_info_classif'

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to do feature selection using K-Best and scoring function  'mutual_info_classif' in scikitlearn. However I am not able to import this function because of this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'mutual_info_classif'
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include the version of scikit you're using too. Problem might be related to [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6922)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ncfirth for your help. My scikitlearn version was 0.17 and I upgraded that to 0.18.